# Finding $\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit: $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

My attempt:

$\begin {align}\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}} &=
\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+n^4\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}}{n^2\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\\ &=
\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2\sqrt{1+n^3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}}{n^2\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\\&= 
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+n^3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}}{\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\end{align}$

Which looks like is equal to $\infty$ because of the $n^3\cdot 1$ but it's wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are taking out factors incorrectly, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a factor out of the square-root, it still gets square-rooted, but you have been squaring them.  For example, $\sqrt{n^2+1}=\sqrt{n^2(1+1/n^2)}=\sqrt{n^2}\sqrt{1+1/n^2}=n\sqrt{1+1/n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\cdot\frac{\frac1{\sqrt n}}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}}}{\sqrt{3+\frac1n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\sqrt\frac23$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}=\lim _{n\to \infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{3n+1}}.
$$
So you only need to determine the limit of the term inside the square root.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{3n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\sqrt{1+1/n^2}}{3+1/n}$$

$$=\frac{1+\sqrt1}3$$

Comment: Why no root for the outer expressions?

Comment: @GinKin, $$\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}$$ right? If the limit $\ge0$

Comment: We were told this is not correct actually..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$\lim\limits _{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
$$= \lim\limits _{n\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{3n+1}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty} \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}{3n+1}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty} \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}}{3n+1}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty} \frac{n+|n|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}{3n+1}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}{3+\frac{1}{n}}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \frac{1+\sqrt{1+0}}{3+0}} $$
$$= \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3}} $$

Comment: We were actually told that inserting the limit inside the root is wrong...

Comment: @GinKin, I'd strongly suggest that you listen to someone else.

Comment: Well I'll ask again but they could say that you can't know the limit is non negative therefore you can't insert it in the root.